# Portable Postgres for Mac?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, flask

I've built a Flask app that will be packaged as a standalone app for users. I built it on Postgres and would like to package a portable version with the app to prevent the need for the user to set up anything system level. I've found this portable version for Windows: https://github.com/garethflowers/postgresql-portable It seems there are some Linux versions floating around, however I can't seem to find a MacOS version.

I started trying to migrate my app to use SQlite instead but it's a giant pain and I'd really just prefer to find portable versions of Postgres for all three platforms. Does anyone know of other portable versions?

Alternatively, if I've built on Postgres using SQLalchemy in Flask is there some other option easier than migrating the whole thing to SQlite? I made extensive use of JSONB and that's the one thing that would make a SQLite migration a giant pain.

Comment: Are you aware that newer versions of sqlite now provide jsonb support natively?

Comment: Maybe consider `docker`, then your whole Postgres database is just a `docker run -d postgres`